# "Node.js Error: Cannot Find Module - Correct File Path and Directory Structure Verified"

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, file-not-found

Title: Node.js Error: Cannot Find Module - Correct File Path and Directory Structure Verified

Body:

I'm attempting to run my Node.js server with the command `node server.js`, but I'm encountering a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error. The error message suggests it can't find my `server.js` file. However, I've verified that the `server.js` file is located in the correct directory (`backend`).

Here's my directory structure:

```
myapp/
├── backend/
│   ├── .env
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── server.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
└── frontend/
    ├── app.js
    ├── supportedLanguages/
    │   └── app.js
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json
```

And here's the error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\farid\myapp\backend\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: node `backend/server.js` ?

Comment: What happens if you try to run `npm install` in your `backend` directory?